# How to update the first element of an array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not a Ruby on Rails developer, like pretty much zero experience.

In a very complex context, I've got this process where I'm replacing commas by semi-colons and also adding a wrapper (double quotes) to each element of an array:

```
@wrap_char = '"'

def escape(text)
  if text.present?
    @wrap_char + text.to_s.tr(',', ';') + @wrap_char
  else
    @wrap_char + @wrap_char
  end
end

['2','SE','STKT','','','',''].map(&method(:escape)).join(',') << "\n"
```

returning this: `"2","SE","STKT","","","",""`

My problem is that I need to exclude the first element from being wrapped, in order to get: `2,"SE","STKT","","","",""`

Ideas will be highly appreciated!

Comment: so i guess you want to convert the first element to integer before join ? or every elements that can be integer will be converted before join ? what if the first element is not an integer ?

Comment: 1.- That would probably work, before the join but after the wrapping (func escape). 
2.- This applies just to the first element. The rest of them will be wrapped either way. 
3.- The first element will always be an integer.
Thank you for taking a look into this!

Comment: is there any case the first element is a float ?

Comment: It would never be a float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `nil.to_s` is `''` so you could simplify your `escape` method to:

```
def escape(text)
  @wrap_char + text.to_s.tr(',', ';') + @wrap_char
end
```

A straight forward approach would be something like this:

```
a = ['2', 'SE', 'STKT', '', '', '', '']
(a[0, 1] + a[1..].map(&method(:escape))).join(',')
```

That'll work as long as `a` is not empty. If you want to allow for `a` to be empty then you can take advantage of `[][1..]` being `nil` and `nil.to_a` being an empty array:

```
(a[0, 1] + a[1..].to_a.map(&method(:escape))).join(',')
```

You could also say:

```
(a[0..0] + a[1..].to_a.map(&method(:escape))).join(',')
```

but the `0..0` range keeps looking at me funny so I prefer `a[0, 1]`. You could also use `#slice` if you don't like the brackets:

```
(a.slice(0, 1) + a.slice(1..).to_a.map(&method(:escape))).join(',')
```

You could also put the "leave the first element alone" logic inside the iteration with things like:

```
a.map.with_index { |e, i| i > 0 ? escape(e) : e }.join(',')
```

Comment: The approach "leave he first element alone" is exactly what I needed and works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```rb
wrap_char = "\""
converts = ['2','SE','STKT','','','',''].map { |x| 
  x =~ /[+-]?[0-9]+/ ? x : "#{wrap_char}#{x.to_s.tr(',', ';')}#{wrap_char}" 
}
puts converts.join(",")
# 2,"SE","STKT","","","",""
```

Comment: Thank you Lam, the approach proposed by @mu suited what I needed.